# SQL querying performance with large number of entries?

Tags: python, sql, flask

So I am trying to serve some files and display info about them on the page with the download link. The info is stored in a sqlite database, and I'm working with Flask and SQLalchemy. My model for a file looks like this:

```
class storedfile(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    path = db.Column(db.Text, unique = True)
    name = db.Column(db.Text) 
    age = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    download_count = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, path, name, age, download_count):
        self.path = path 
        self.name = name 
        self.age = age
        self.download_count = download_count



    def __repr__(self):
        return '<storedfile % r>' % self.name
```

When loading the page, I am retrieving the info about the file by filtering by path(every path is unique, the folder names are randomly generated) like this:

```
fileinfo = storedfile.query.filter_by(path = os.path.join(new_folder_path, filename)).first()
```

The paths aren't sorted, if there is a large number of paths in the index, will this significantly slow down performance? Is there a better/faster way of sorting and querying them?

Comment: This isn't really a Flask or SQLAlchemy specific question, btw. This is pure database theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, filtering by exact strings is not going to be a problem. That's what databases are good at; building efficient indexes for exact matches.

Your exact string match on a column with a uniqueness constraint is one of the simplest indexes a database can build and maintain, you are doing it right.

Comment: To be more accurate, it _will_ "significantly slow down performance", just not significantly enough to matter—searching a relational database by exact string match is usually O(log N), not O(1), so with 10000000 rows it'll probably take a few times longer than with 10—but no worse than a few times longer, which is usually nowhere slow enough to be your bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you. This is my first time working with relational databases(or any databases for that matter), and SQLalchemy made things so easy I got lazy and didn't research them much.